# Eclipse: What is the Difference Between "dynamic web project" and a "java ee web project"

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

Not sure if this is a question for Stackoverflow or Programmers.
I want to develop a frontend webproject with eclipse.

The frontend will receive it's data from EJBs.

I have the jboss tools installed. I can now select between a "dynamic web project" and a "java ee web project". Where is the difference and which one should I choose and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Jboss [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/whatsnew/central/central-news-1.0.0.M5.html), java EE web project "generates a Java EE 6 web project with JSF 2, JPA 2, REST and CDI support enabled.

In your scenario, JPA 2, REST and CDI could be more than you need. You should go with dynamic web project, which is the standard profile for web applications.

You could insert additional features such as JPA later, if you need them.

Comment: thanks! I have rest-services implemented in my backend, so I will go with a dynamic web project